# Which Windows 2008 Server edition for a small business (exchange, webhosting, internal file sharing)?

Tags: windows-server-2008

Yes I know, the question sound silly and the answer could be "omg, take Small Business Server". But as I am a Linux guy who doesn't know anything about windows Server, I don't know about potential issues and traps in the Win7 Server Licensing System. It must be WIndows and not Linux because it should work together with some proprietary CAD system. All the server has to be capable of is:

- Handle Exchange, Outlook etc.
- Host small company website
- 3-5 clients will need access to the Server

What I don't know is, e.g, if IIS is included with the Small Business Edition. So, is the Small Business Edition OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, IIS is included with SBS. It should fit your needs just fine.

http://www.microsoft.com/sbs/en/us/compare-features.aspx